# How can I get a Microsoft Access combobox to behave like a listbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

With a listbox when you click a letter it takes you to the first match for that letter.  When you click that letter again it takes you to the second match for that letter and so on.

Is there a way to get a combo box to behave that way?

Comment: That is how comboboxes work in Access. As you type letters, the word is "guessed". Is this not happening for you? Listboxes do not generally behave that way.

Comment: @Remou: Actually, I think what Seth wants is this behavior:  assume a list of "Alice", "Bill", "Bob", "Charles".  User presses "B" and Bill is highlighted.  Then user presses "B" again and now Bob is highlighted.  In a listbox, Bob would indeed be highlighted.  In a combobox, BB would be in the combo box and of course there would be no matches.  Seth: Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Essentially, you are trying to make the Access combo box behave like a dropdown box.  Access has no native dropdown box; largely because the combo box fills this need in most cases.  And having two controls that look the same but behave differently would detract from the user interface.  With that in mind, you should probably do *something* to your pseudo-dropdown controls to differentiate them from standard combo-boxes.  Perhaps a different special effect: sunken for combos and raised/flat for the dropdowns, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of for a combobox is the *Autocomplete* property.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with a ***combobox*** when you click a letter it takes you to the first match for that letter OR select from a pulldown... and with a ***listbox*** you have to select from a pull down.  I think you have it the other way around in your question.  You may just need to make your fields be comboboxes not listboxes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a combo box behave that way unless you want to code it.  However, coding it is not all that bad.  The following code can probably be improved upon (and should at least have some error handling added) but it will get the job done.

Assume you have a form with a combo box named ComboBox1 and the `OnKeyDown`, `OnKeyPress`, and `OnKeyUp` properties are all set to `[Event Procedure]`:

```
Private Sub Combo1_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
Dim Cbo As ComboBox, i As Integer, Val As Variant, CurIndex As Integer
    Set Cbo = Me.ActiveControl
    Select Case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyBack, vbKeyDelete
        Cbo.Value = Null
    Case Else
        CurIndex = Cbo.ListIndex
        For i = CurIndex + 1 To Cbo.ListCount - 1
            If Left(Cbo.ItemData(i), 1) = Chr(KeyCode) Then
                Cbo.Value = Cbo.ItemData(i)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
        For i = 0 To CurIndex
            If Left(Cbo.ItemData(i), 1) = Chr(KeyCode) Then
                Cbo = Cbo.ItemData(i)
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next i
    End Select
    KeyCode = StripKeyCode(KeyCode)
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    KeyAscii = StripKeyCode(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Sub Combo1_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    KeyCode = StripKeyCode(KeyCode)
End Sub

Private Function StripKeyCode(KeyCode As Integer) As Integer
    Select Case KeyCode
    Case vbKeyUp, vbKeyDown, vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight, vbKeyTab, vbKeyF4
        'Allow navigation keys to pass through
        StripKeyCode = KeyCode
    Case Else
        StripKeyCode = 0
    End Select
End Function
```

I doubt the performance will be all that great in a combobox with a ton of choices. Then again, you should probably only be using this technique in situations where the number of items that start with the same letter will be small (eg, less than 5).